# vim DelimitMate

Tags: vim

With the DelimitMate, it auto generates the closing parentheses. When I'm finished typing inside the parenthesis, what key strokes do I press to quickly go to the right of the closing parenthesis? (Right now I have to manually press ESC then 'a')

Comment: What about `)` or `<Right>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a custom map. I guess you want to go to the right of the closing parenthesis while you're in `insert` mode. Just add to your `.vimrc` this mapping:

```
:inoremap <F8> <ESC>f)a
```

In this way, while your in `insert mode` and you've finished to write inside the parenthesis, <kbd>F8</kbd> will bring your cursor ad the right of the closing parenthesis.
If you want you can change the mapped key, using another key instead of <kbd>F8</kbd>.

As Kent said in the comment a more general solution would be:

```
:inoremap <F8> <ESC>%%a
```

Which will work for `[` and `{` brackets.

Comment: this what I had at very first. the problem is, you have to map `]`, `}` too

Comment: @Kent: yes If he needs a more general solution your's works better. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The idea of these auto-closing plugins (like the original feature implementation found in IDEs like Eclipse) is that you just **type** the closing character to go over it. The plugin should detect this situation and instead of inserting the character jumps over the existing, auto-inserted one.

If that's not working for you, there are several plugin alternatives on offer. The [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters#Plugins) has a list of them.

Answer (score 9):

With [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/master/doc/delimitMate.txt#L379-L407), `Shift-tab` will jump out of the current delimiter and `Control-G g` will get you out of nested delimiters. No need to remap anything.

Answer (score 5):

You could try auto-pairs's Fly Mode

eg:

```
( hello| world )

press ) at |

( hello world )|
```

If jump incorrect, use `<M-b>` to do the back insert.

eg:

```
(hello| world()

press ) at |

(hello world()|

press <M-b>

(hello)| world()
```

Repository: https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs

Plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599

add

```
let g:AutoPairsFlyMode=1
```

to .vimrc to turn Fly Mode on

Answer (score 1):

I kinda agree with Atropo on this one: if you want to stick with DelimitMate then the least disruption to your workflow might be to make a custom imap to get to the other side of the auto inserted character.

Personally I prefer to have more control over where/when the characters are auto-inserted, and how I can navigate around the auto-inserted characters; [UltiSnips](https://launchpad.net/ultisnips) or [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) does that for me. Maybe they're more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you typing on a new line, you try `A` which will append text at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I have autoClose installed. what I am doing currently is ("I" is cursor)

```
- (xxxxI)
- ( xxxxI )
- ( xxxxIxx )
- text (xxxxI) other text
- text ( xxxxI ) other text
- text ( xxxxIxx ) other text
```

I just make a mapping, to `<esc>%%a` then in above case, the cursor will move to `(...)I..whatever`

it doesn't work for quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but note that it can be done easily without any custom mappings. In insert mode, you can press `<C-O>` (a default mapping) to enter a "one shot" normal mode where you can enter a single normal mode command.

So to answer your question, what you could do is `<C-O>a`.